# Bloomberg API xbbg wrapper for Python - Getting Portfolio Data

Tags: python, pandas, bloomberg

I am trying to extract data from Bloomberg PRTU, at a specific point in time.

The following works for the current portfolio:

```
from xbbg import blp, pipeline
blp.bds('U1234567-8 Client', flds='Portfolio_Data', use_port=True)
```

I need to extract data at a specific point in time. The following code used to work for R blpapi wrapper:

```
overrides = c("REFERENCE_DATE" = port_time)
getPortfolio("U1234567-8 Client","Portfolio_Data", overrides = overrides)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out an answer using the following syntax:

```
blp.bds('A20065594-121 Client', flds='Portfolio_Data', use_port=True, Reference_Date = '20210301')
```